# Whcih API should I use to auto complete cities , streets and suburbs?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I tried to find a big database of Cities , Streets and Suburbs of my country to make an autocomplete search input but I couldn't find any good source of such database...
I was thinking to use Google autocomplete API for that purpose but I couldn't understand how to get the data I need with that,

What api should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API you want to use is Places API,

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro

From the Places API, the request you want to use is Place Autocomplete Requests,

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete

In case you're using Maps JS API there is no need to use the web services endpoints.
Autocomplete for Addresses and Search Terms is available in the JS API

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

Example,

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Comment: It looks good , the only missing part of information that I need is a suburb which appears on google maps , but not on the autocomplete any idea where can I get it?

Comment: Try tweaking with the `(regions)` type collection. I can see a `locality` but also a `sublocality` type that may include what you want. Anyway, `suburb` is not exactly what we would call an official Administrative Division. https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete